$A \subset \mathbb{R}^2: 0<x<1 \ , 0<y<1$ and $f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^3}$. Is $f \chi_A$ Lebesgue measurable? Is $f$ integrable?
$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the inequalities $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$. Function $f$ defined almost everywhere by the formula:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^3}$$

Is the function $f \chi_A$ Lebesgue measurable on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Edit:
As mentioned by Anne Bauval in the comments down below, I did this one wrong and I have no idea what does it mean for $f \chi_A$ to be measurable. Let alone checking that.

Show that $f$ is not integrable on $A$ in the Lebesgue sense.

Let $T$ be the lower triangular subregion of $[0,1]^2$ whose vertices are $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1).$ Then, letting $dA$ denote area measure, we have:
$$\int_{[0,1]^2}|f| \ dA \ge \int_T |f| \ dA$$
From Fubini, the integral on the right equals:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3} \ dy \ dx$$
In the inner integral, let $y=xz$ Then $dy=xdz$ and the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^2z(x^2-z^2x^2)}{(x^2+z^2x^2)^3} \ xdz \ dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^4(z-z^2)}{x^6(1+z^2)^3} \ xdz \ dx  = \int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\int_0^1 \frac{z-z^2}{(1+z^2)^3} \ dz \ dx$$
In the last integral, the inner integral is some positive number $C.$ We are left with
$$\int_0^1 \frac{C}{x} \ dx = \infty$$
This shows $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1]^2$

Your answer to question 1 makes no sense. Moreover, I think you mistyped and misinterpreted $f\chi_A$, which is the product of $f$ by the indicator function of $A$.

Yes, I thought that question 1 is somewhat weird. The second one makes more sense for me. What is $f_{\chi_A}$ then? How to calculate that?

I thought $f_{\chi_A}$ means just and indicator function over A and to tell if it's integrable I can just integrate it.

As I said, I think question 1 asked to prove that the product of $f$ by $\chi_A$ is measurable. And even if you misinterpreted it as proving that $\chi_A$ alone is measurable, what you wrote did not prove it. You confused measurable with integrable.

Your answer to question 2 is fine. You might be interested by the many posts about this on MSE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Thank you. I will use your advice in future posts.

I'm not sure. I see that the answer provided by RRL shows that the function is not lebesgue integrable (as I did in my answer to 2nd question), but I don't see any answer to 1st question.

The second question was imo the main one. I essentially answered the first in the comments above. In your edit you wrote I have no idea what does it mean for $f \chi_A$ to be measurable. Let alone checking that. Don't you know what measurability of a function means? and various sufficient conditions for it?

Also, I'm not sure if my answer to 2nd one is correct. I integrate over $x$ from $0$ to $1$, but the set specified in the question doesn't include $x = 0$ nor $x = 1$. On the other hand those 2 points are of measure $0$, so maybe that's not a problem?

Not a problem ideed.

As for the first one, can I just say that the set $A$ is measurable and the function $f$ is continous on that set. And from that, any continous function defined on a measurable set is measurable $\implies f \chi_A$ is measurable?

Yes you can! Or "any product of two measurable functions (like $f$ and $\chi_A$) is measurable".

Great, thank you.
